# Detect rotation changes in iOS

Tags: ios, interface, nsnotificationcenter, screen-rotation, autorotate

I am making an iOS app that needs to do a little interface rearrangement upon rotation. I am trying to detect this by implementing `- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note`, but this gives me notifications for when the device is face up or face down.

I want a way to just get notified when the interface changes orientations.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since iOS 8, above methods were deprecated, and the proper way to handle and detect device rotation is:

[-(void) viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id )coordinator;](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIContentContainer/viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:)

To detect device orientation, you should (according to documentation): *call the [statusBarOrientation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/statusBarOrientation) method to determine the device orientation*

Answer (score 28):

There are several method where you can do that, you can find them in the [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
– willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
```

You could also do it in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method, but be careful with it, because it is called on the screen appearance too, and whenever you add a subview.

**Edit:**

Solution now deprecated, see accepted answer.

Comment: Note that all three of those are deprecated in iOS 8. They recommend using a variant that transitions to size instead.

Answer (score 9):

Since iOS 8 this is the correct way to do it.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in
        // This is called during the animation
    }, completion: { context in
        // This is called after the rotation is finished. Equal to deprecated `didRotate`
    })
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

}
```