# Xcode / iOS / iPhone How to set event to UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel

Please give me an advice.
I create UILabels programmatically (dynamic).
Is there is a chance to add Event to them?

What I want by steps:

1. I create UILabel;
2. I set Event to it; (NSNotification?)
3. When I do some action (rotate, for example) I want that Label is changed or removed. An extended example: I create Labels and when I rotate device I want that part of them (which with attached Events) disappear in animation.

I create a lot of Labels, so I can't just set them global variables. And I can't set them tags unlimited. So `UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:labelCount` not a solution. Getting element by 'viewWithTag' has one more trouble - when set animation to that element and that element already in animation happens collision - they plays one over other...

I create Labels like this:

`CGRect *labelFrame = CGRectMake(left, top, width, height);
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
label.text = @"Hi, I'm one of these army of labels";
[self.view addSubview:label];`

PS: Sorry for English.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a `UIViewController` that has a bunch of labels. I would recommend an IBOutletConnection for storing a reference to all of your labels (assuming storyboard).

```
//You will need to connect all of these labels through Interface Builder.
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *labels;
```

In one of the following rotation methods ([Detect rotation changes in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369251/ios-detect-rotation-changes)) do your rearranging.

```
//Called whenever orientation changes
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    for (UILabel *label in self.labels) {
        //Make each label disappear here.
    }
}
```